# Making a case for Kentico 9 vs 8.2

Tags: model-view-controller, kentico

We will be developing a new web site for a client who already has a Kentico 8.2 license.  I am trying to make a case for developing the site using Kentico 9.  Some key features I have found so far include:

- faster performance (how much in real-world terms?)
- better integration with .Net MVC
- content staging tasks can be synchronized per user account
- better rollback functionality: previously we had to make full database backups, content staging in Kentico 8.2 causes issues for restoring previous versions of a page.
- built in source control support for GIT

It looks like Kentico integration with the client's existing database may be possible.  Has anyone done this?  What are the limitations or caveats?

Is there a discount for upgrading the license from 8.2 to 9?

Thanks in advance for your feedback!

Answer (score 1):

> faster performance (how much in real-world terms?)

- there are major ([official](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Release+notes+-+Kentico+9)) improvements for content and contact management

> better integration with .Net MVC

- there is whole new way to [develop](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Developing+MVC+applications) sites using ASP.NET MVC with Kentico

> content staging tasks can be synchronized per user account

- there is pretty good [blogpost](http://devnet.kentico.com/articles/staging-improvements) describing new staging improvements

> better rollback functionality: previously we had to make full database
>   backups, content staging in Kentico 8.2 causes issues for restoring
>   previous versions of a page.

- I am not sure what do you mean by new rollback functionality

> built in source control support for GIT

- you might confused with [continuous integration](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Setting+up+continuous+integration) feature

You can find release notes with all new features and improvements [here](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Release+notes+-+Kentico+9).

> It looks like Kentico integration with the client's existing database
>   may be possible. Has anyone done this? What are the limitations or
>   caveats?

- there is tested [upgrade utility](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Upgrading+to+Kentico+9) for upgrading to Kentico 9

> Is there a discount for upgrading the license from 8.2 to 9?

- for pricing you should definitely contact [Kentico sales department](http://www.kentico.com/company/contact/our-offices)

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.  Regarding integration of an existing client database - we are actually looking into building a new site (not upgrading) while using the existing database (if possible/practical).

Comment: If I understand you right this should be supported scenario.

Comment: By 'rollback' I mean restoring a page to a previous version after synchronization (using content staging).

Comment: Do you mean staging synchronization? Imho I think that restore to previous version should create you new staging task in older version, too - so I think this is not the new feature (but not sure).

Answer (score 1):

[See the answer I posted on the DevNet](http://devnet.kentico.com/questions/making-a-case-for-kentico-9-vs-8-2) (which by the way, no need to cross-post on both)

If they have a license for 8.2, is their maintenance current? If so, simply go to the client portal and upgrade it for free. This can be done without any cost. Either way, the licensing cost doesn't come from the version, it comes from the type (base, ultimate, ems, etc.).

So assuming they purchased their license about a year ago, their maintenance should be current or close to current and you either get current on your maintenance or just go to the client portal and see if it will allow you to upgrade your license and get a new key for v9.

If they don't have the site built, there is no reason to build it on v8.2 at all.

Comment: Thank you, it looks like this may be a possibility.  Are you familiar with the Kentico 8.2 and 9 support road-map going forward?

Comment: What are you looking for specifically @D3v regarding the roadmap?